# Limit of $\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{|C_1a^x+C_2(ka)^x|^{A}+|C_3|^{A}-|C_1a^x+C_2(ka)^x-C_3|^{A}}{a^xD_1+(ka)^xD_2}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, derivatives

I want to calculate the following limit

$$\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{|C_1a^x+C_2(ka)^x|^{A}+|C_3|^{A}-|C_1a^x+C_2(ka)^x-C_3|^{A}}{a^xD_1+(ka)^xD_2}$$

knowing that $-1<a<1$, $-1<k<1$ and $1<A<2$.

I proceed in the following way.

Since for $x \to \infty$ we have $\left[\frac{0}{0}\right]$, I use the de L'Hopital's rule.

$$\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{|C_1a^x+C_2(ka)^x|^{A}+|C_3|^{A}-|C_1a^x+C_2(ka)^x-C_3|^{A}}{a^xD_1+(ka)^xD_2}=\left[\frac{0}{0}\right]=\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{A|C_1a^x+C_2(ka)^x|^{A-1}{\rm sgn}(C_1a^x+C_2(ka)^x)(C_1a^x\log(a)+C_2(ka)^x\log(ka)) ...}{a^x\log(a)D_1+(ka)^x\log(ka)D_2}\\\frac{-A|C_1a^x+C_2(ka)^x-C_3|^{A-1}{\rm sgn}(C_1a^x+C_2(ka)^x-C_3)(C_1a^x\log(a)+C_2(ka)^x\log(ka))}{a^x\log(a)D_1+(ka)^x\log(ka)D_2}$$

Now, I take the expression $a^x$ in front of both nominator and denominator and reduce it obtaining

$$\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{A|C_1a^x+C_2(ka)^x|^{A-1}{\rm sgn}(C_1a^x+C_2(ka)^x)(C_1\log(a)+C_2(k)^x\log(ka)) ...}{\log(a)D_1+(k)^x\log(ka)D_2}\\\frac{-A|C_1a^x+C_2(ka)^x-C_3|^{A-1}{\rm sgn}(C_1a^x+C_2(ka)^x-C_3)(C_1\log(a)+C_2(k)^x\log(ka))}{\log(a)D_1+(k)^x\log(ka)D_2}$$

and finally I obtain $\frac{A|C_3|^{A-1}{\rm sgn}(C_3)C_1\log(a)}{\log(a)D_1}$ as the result.

Is this reasoning correct?

My main question is:

At some point, I calculate the derivative of $a^x$ which is equal to $a^x\log(a)$ and I am sure that it is correct in the case of $0<a<1$, but what if $-1<a<0$? Can I write that the derivative of $a^x$ is $a^x\log(a)$ when $-1<a<0$? If not, how should I calculate this limit in the case of $-1<a<0$?